# attach MouseArea to MapParameter

Tags: qml, qt5, mapbox-gl

[image]i want to display geojson file on maps and make these shapes clickable to show more details about a building for example.

what i get is just a coordinate ... i need to get geojson object of building clicked

```
    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "mapboxgl"
            PluginParameter {
                name: "mapboxgl.access_token"
                value:"sk.eyJ1IjoiYWxub29yLXNjaG9vbCIsImEiOiJjbGF1cmd0YTEwOWNoM3ByNjdxaW0yZXZiIn0.-RGpdTPTSBqrUGc65oLPNQ"
            }

 MouseArea {
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
            anchors.fill: parent
 onClicked: {
                mouse.accepted=true
                if (mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton) {
                    var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y));
                    console.log(coord.latitude, coord.longitude)
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(mouse) )
                } else {

                }
            }

        }
```

```
 DynamicParameter  {
            type: "source"

            property var name: "buildingSource"
            property var sourceType: "geojson"
            property var data: ":building.json"
        }

        DynamicParameter  {
            type: "layer"
            property var name: "buildinLayer"
            property var layerType: "fill"
            property var source: "buildingSource"
        }
        DynamicParameter  {
            type: "paint"
            property var layer: "buildinLayer"
            property var fillColor: "#bbb"
        }
```

Comment: what is MapParameter? what is `these shapes`? I see no shapes in your code. and now I see you add MapArea to all the map. please complete your code and clarify the question.

Comment: these shapes are defined in geojson file ... you can have an example in this project 
https://github.com/tmpsantos/qmapboxglapp

Comment: i added mouseArea to Map .. i expected when clicking on object newly added to map to getting some info about it but what i get is just geo coordinate (lat ,long) ... it's hard to search among every building bounding box to know if mouse click (lat,long) inside this building or not

Comment: in mapbox js have similar feature like this example
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/